# Is also second wire in power plant ( from alternator for example) also connected to ground?

Tags: electricity

If one wire from AC supply is "hot" and goes to one end of power plug (let's keep it simple) and second end of power plug is neutral a goes to ground in "power plant", than also second wire from AC supply goes to ground to make circuit complete ?

Answer (score -1):

A power plant delivers three lines of AC which have a phase difference of 120° and add up to 0. So they usually do not have one end in earth.

Comment: Ok, but I'm considering different and simplified problem. Let's have alternator with two wires - one goes to power plug and where goes second one ? Because in power plug one  wire is hot and second one should be grounded  (zero potential). So this neutral wire from plug should be somehow connected to our alternator ...what I'm asking if is it through the "ground" (whatever that actually means) ?

Comment: With the exception of a few IT systems, a three phase "Y" system is generally grounded at the center and a three phase $\Delta$ system is generally grounded at a corner.

Comment: Yes in this case it has nothing to do with AC or DC the second second plug of the  your power supply and the second plug of your generator or batterie scold connect to the same conducting medium, In your car this would be the metal body of the car, in your house usually  "earth" meaning  your waterlines connected to ground or some thick cable buried in the ground .

Comment: I'm talking about power plants. The OP is referring to power plants.

Comment: Ok, thank you both. Bod D: sorry for missleading OP. Trula: Ok, thank you too. So can I consider "ground" from power plug point of view to be returning path with big resistance ? If yes, is value of this resistance considered in calculations ? And neutral wire is "safe" because touching neutral  is just connection : one wire of supply, resistance (ground), person resistance, ground ...so without return path ?

Comment: Oh, I´ve just realised that, ground should have quite SMALL resistance, so it can be neglected in calculations. Neutral should be safe as i wrote in previous comment. And  touching neutral or hot wire or case of mentioned car under current is "safe" because we are parallel circuit with big resistance (like birds on wires). Like this it´s make sense for me now. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes you are safe, but birds can sit on the "hot" wire, as you cold touch the "hot" wire if you have good insulation against ground.

Comment: Yes, and am right in other things? Just to be sure...

Comment: @NiobTitan You need to understand that although the neutral or grounded conductor is connected to ground, the load current flowing in that conductor does not flow through the ground. The only resistance is the resistance of the conductor itself.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but according to the comments load current must goes through the ground. I understand, that ground is not Earth, rather some wire or  any conductor with small resistance, in that case and only it that case I can neglect resistance of grounding. If, according to you Bob D, current does not flow  through the  ground, so where it goes??

Comment: Bob ha some misunderstanding, what you think is right, and you asked the right question

Comment: @trula I have no misunderstanding of how current flows in the neutral (grounded) circuit conductor. I leave it at that.

Comment: @Trula, sorry for my bad english. Whatever that statement after "what" belong to me?

Comment: I tried to say you are right.@ Bob D can you explain how the circuit is closed?